# Express Validator 5.3 - required parameter if second parameter is included inside a given array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

I was looking for a validator that requires a specific parameter if there's a parameter that equals to a specific value. Maybe something like this:

```
const allowedsMethods = ['A', 'B'];

...

check('method').custom(method => allowedMethods.includes(method))
check('paramA').requireIfContains('method', ['A'])
check('paramB').requireIfContains('method', ['A'])
check('paramAorB').requireIfContains('method', ['A', 'B'])
```

- If `method` is contained inside `['A']`, then the property `paramA` will be required.
- If `method` is contained inside `['B']`, then the property `paramA` will be required.
- If `method` is contained inside `['A', 'B']`, then the property `paramA` will be required.

I was looking at the [currently available validators](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) and I didn't find something that would fit my needs. I tried to figure out how can I achieve this by using a custom validator, but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  Are you trying to figure out how to dynamically check if a passed in object in the second parameter contains a value in your array?  Can you post code examples of what you've tried to accomplish this?  That might help me understand your scenario a bit better.

Comment: Hey @Jim , The real scenario is a method of payments. The first option is charge by token, which I need to pass a token and the amount of value I want to charge. The second method is a single charge, which then I have to specify the card information. The third part is a bulk payment. The thing is, the token parameter is required only if the method is set to charge by token. CVV, CID and card number should be required when the method is bulk payments or single charge. I hope I made it clearer for you.

Comment: This sounds like a validator you'll have to write yourself.  To answer your question though;  You'd have to check that the parameter coming in is the type and object you expect based on your business logic.  Something like `function(a, b, c){
if(typeof c === undefined) {throw new Error()}
}`  Or are you looking for something else?